# Subviews of a NSCollectionViewItem's view are always nil

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I have a very basic setup with a `NSCollectionView`. I have a subclassed `NSCollectionViewItem` which is used as the `itemPrototype` for the collection view. The collection view item has a view.

Using Interface Builder, I added an `NSImageView` to the collection view item's view and connected an `IBOutlet` to the instance of my collection view item subclass. The property for the `IBOutlet` is uses `retain` for its memory management.

My goal is to hide or show this image view whenever the selection state for the collection view item changes. But within the `setSelected:` method my property for the image view is nil, even though I am 100% sure its outlet is connected, its property is set to retain and i have not unset or released the image view.

I had a similar issue with collection view items where an activity indicator added to the view was always nil too. Why does this happen and what do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I now, IBOutlets pointing to non-top level objects in nib/xib file should be defined (weak).

Are you sure you have changed the class of NSCollectionView item correctly?

When breaking in setSelected:, and doing a po self in the debugger console, are you seeing the name of your class?